# Move Object toward mouse click in 2D top down Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am facing a problem with making an object move toward the mouse click position.
My view is a 2D top down view ( y-axis is vertical ) but when I get the position of mouse click. I add force to the object is starts rotating around the position in x-axis.

```
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);
while (!firstTime) {
        MousePosition = MainCamera.WorldToScreenPoint (transform.position);
        CheckSpeed(Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, MousePosition));
        Quaternion rotation = transform.rotation;
        Vector3 dir = rotation * Vector3.forward;
        this.rigidbody.AddForce (dir*100);
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, dir ,Time.deltaTime* forwardSpeed);      
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1f);
    }
    yield break;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off using MoveTowards :

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, destination, CONSTANT);
```

You can do this in an Update() and it will move **transform.position** until it reaches **destination**.

I would also avoid your yields there. Move this over to the Update() function and use booleans to make sure you dont move your object if it arrived. For example, you do something like :

```
Mathf.Abs(Vector3.Distance(position, destination)) <= EPSILON
```

Also, in 2D, the best way to get the mouse position is something like :

```
Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero)
```

You want to map the mouse to the object's space, not the other way around.